# How $\frac{1}{x+1}-\log{(1+\frac{1}{x})}<0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

To prove that $\frac{1}{x+1}-\log{(1+\frac{1}{x})}<0$ $\forall x>0$:
If I consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-\log{(1+\frac{1}{x})}=\frac{1}{x+1}-\log{(x+1)}-\log{x}$ then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x}>0 \forall x>0$ then $f(x)>f(0)=0$.
to do: check if my idea is right

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes I have just done it.

Comment: Check that $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}-\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}>0$ but as $f(0)$ is undefined, the monotonicity method does not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the mother of all inequalities about the exponential function:
$$ e^t\ge 1+t\qquad\text{for all }t\in\Bbb R$$
(with equality iff $t=0$).

Given $x>0$, we plug in $t=-\frac 1{1+x}\ne 0$ to arrive at
$$ e^{-\frac1{1+x}}> 1-\frac1{1+x}=\frac x{1+x}.$$
As both sides are positive, we take reciprocals and arrive at
$$ e^{\frac1{1+x}}<\frac{1+x}x=1+\frac1x.$$
Taking logarithms,
$$ \frac1{1+x}<\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right).$$

Comment: Ok thanks...but my request it's specificallly to check my idea...

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\log{(1+\frac{1}{x})}=\frac{1}{x+1}+\int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t(1+t)^2}> \frac{1}{x+1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote $f(x)$ incorrectly.
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-\log{(x+1)}+\log{x}$$
so that
$$f'(x)=-\frac1{(x+1)^2}-\frac1{x+1}+\frac1x=\frac{1}{x(x+1)^2}>0$$
for all $x>0$.  So $f(x)$ is an increasing function on $(0,\infty)$. Since $\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ we conclude that $f(x)<0$ in $(0,\infty)$.