# Prove $\frac{1}{x+1} \leq \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am seeking assistance in proving the inequality $ \frac{1}{x+1} \leq \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) $ for $( x \geq 1 ).$

This inequality can be seen geometrically. Plot $\frac{1}{t}$ and observe that the area under the curve between $t=x$ and $t=x+1$ is $\ln(1+x)-\ln(x) = \ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$. This is greater than the area of the rectangle whose breadth is $1=(x+1)-x$, the distance between $x$ and $x+1$ is $1$, and length is $\frac{1}{1+x}$.

By taking $f(x) = \ln(1 + \frac{1}{x}) - \frac{1}{x+1}$  observed that $f'(x)= -\frac{1}{x (x+1)^2} < 0$ for $x\geq1$. I need a non-geometrical proof.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3979019/42969

Comment: **Answer :** Without calculus, you can also reach the proof by simply applying the well-known inequality $e^x≥x+1$ .
Using the substitution $x\longmapsto -\ln x,\thinspace \forall x>0$ we have

$$
\begin{align}&\frac 1x≥1-\ln x\\
\iff &\ln x≥1-\frac 1x \color{#c00}{\tag 1}\end{align}
$$

This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}\ln \left(1+\frac 1x\right)&≥1-\frac {1}{1+\frac 1x}\\
&=\frac {1}{x+1} \end{align}
$$

Finally, note that the derived inequality holds $\color{#c00}{\forall x>0}$ .